# Javascript Reduce an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-5

When I reduce the array, I am trying to get the number zero, but I dont clearly understand the behaviour of the function

```
[].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
  return Number(previousValue) + Number(currentValue);
});
```

result

```
TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

seems that if the array is empty I can't reduce it

```
[""].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
  return Number(previousValue) + Number(currentValue);
});
```

result

```
""
```

If the only element in the array is an empty string, retrieves an empty string

Answer (score 335, accepted):

**[The second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** is for initial value.

```
[].reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
  return Number(previousValue) + Number(currentValue);
}, 0);
```

or using ES6:

```
[].reduce( (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + currentValue, 0);
```

Comment: By "initial value" do you mean the default?

Comment: We definitely need the <3 emoticon in stackoverflow

Answer (score 31):

Both behaviors are according to [the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.21).

You cannot `reduce` an empty array unless you explicitly provide an initial "accumulated" value as the second argument:

> If no initialValue was provided, then previousValue will be equal to
>   the first value in the array and currentValue will be equal to the
>   second. It is a TypeError if the array contains no elements and
>   initialValue is not provided.

If the array has at least one element then providing an initial value is optional. However, if one is not provided then the first element of the array is used as the initial value and `reduce` continues to process the rest of the array elements by invoking your callback. In your case the array only contains a single element, so that element becomes the initial value and also final value, since there are no more elements to be processed through the callback.

Answer (score 2):

*Just ran into this myself and want to give this an answer with a more simple yet modern JavaScript example.*

JavaScript's array reduce function iterates over an array (here `list`) and reduces it to a new result (here `sum`) by computing each item (here `value`) in the array with the accumulator (here `acc`):

```
const sum = list.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value);
```

Most reduce operations *prefer* to operate on an initial accumulator (second argument, also called initial value). In our example, it's indeed even mandatory, because otherwise the sum operation wouldn't work. We want to sum our values with an initial value of 0:

```
const sum = list.reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
```

The initial value for a reduce function is its second argument (here `0`). So if you come across the  error:

```
TypeError: Reduce of empty array with no initial value
```

It just means that you have to provide an initial (empty) array for your reduce operation, because if you provide an empty array (here `list`) to start with, it doesn't work and complains with this error. In order to fix it, provide an empty array as second argument:

```
const exponentials = list.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc = acc.concat(value * value);
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: For added clarity I suggest adding `const list = [];` to the beginning of the example (it's necessary for anything to work)

Answer (score 2):

```
[].reduce(function (total, curr) {return total + curr;},0);
```

I'm fixed add 0 default value and "" using we can fix

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the previous value must be defined first, because it is equivalent to assigning a value to a variable previousValue

`let previousValue = 0;`
is different from
`let previousValue;`