# Angular pick first 3 arrays from array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have list of arrays in an array. I need to pick first 3.

For example i have this :

```
[{[1]},{[2]},{[3]},{[4]}]
```

Sorry i know it's not a proper array i am attaching my console

[image]

This is my arrays look like and i need to pick just first 3 . And also can i restructure my array like this in one array ?

```
[{1},{2},{3}]
```

Comment: try arr.length = 3

Comment: The console shows an array of objects, not an array of arrays

Comment: Maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33679850/11498076

Answer (score 3):

You can either use slice

```
array.slice(0, 3);
```

if you want to modify the original array use,

```
arr.length = 3;
```

**Demo :**

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

var newArr = arr.slice(0,3);

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

A good function is to use the slice function from array. 
An example looks like this:

```
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Lemon", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var citrus = fruits.slice(0, 3);
```

The result will be citrus = Banana,Orange,Lemon

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the original array use splice();
e.g.

```
    let array=['1','2','3','4','5'];
array.splice(3);
 array; // 1,2,3;
```

But if you want that changes should not reflect original array use slice() method.

```
    let array=['1','2','3','4','5'];
let finalArray=array.slice(0,3);
 array; // 1,2,3,4,5;
finalArray; // 1,2,3;
```