# Find largest number in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays

-- My question concerns an array, not an object, which the similar question is for --

I have a multidimensional array, where I need to find the array with the largest number from a set position, then return the first item of that array.

I have this working, but feel there must be a better way to acheive this.

Here is my code, which is working in testing:

```
slidesArray = [["1",500],["2",750],["3",501]];

var EmpArr = []
var x = 0;
var len = slidesArray.length;
for (x; x < len; x++) {
    EmpArr.push(Math.max(slidesArray[x][1]))
}

var largestResult = Math.max(...EmpArr);

var result = slidesArray.filter(function(v,i) {
    return v[1] === largestResult;
});
```

In this example, I need to check `slidesArray[0][1]`, `slidesArray[1][1]` and `slidesArray[2][1]` to find which is the largest number. Then I want to return the first element of the array which contains the largest, so here '2'.

Comment: "*My question concerns an array, not an object, which the similar question is for*" there is no difference, though. Arrays *are* objects. If you can do it by grabbing a property, you can do it by grabbing an index. Or can you point out why that cannot be done?

Comment: Duplicate of: [Return object with highest value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36941115) both solutions posted here already exist there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it, using [**`Array#reduce()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a one liner code:

```
slidesArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
    return (acc[1] === undefined || val[1] > acc[1] ) ? val : acc;
}, [[]])[0];
```

This way you can avoid using `Math.max()` and multiple iterations.

**Demo:**

```js
var slidesArray = [["1",500],["2",750],["3",501]];

var result = slidesArray.reduce((acc, val) => {
        return (acc[1] === undefined || val[1] > acc[1] ) ? val : acc;
    }, [[]])[0];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941425

Comment: @VLAZ Well seen, but I haven't seen that solution, I just tried to play around with `reduce` and this is what I got, and as you said in your first comment the linked solution uses an array of objects and this one uses an array of arrays.

Comment: As I said in my first comment, I missunderstood your comment in the question, I thought you were  for reopening the question, anyway thanks for the offense in your comment, @ccdavies please unaccept the answer so I can delete it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You wrote a loop that can be replaced with the map function. This is basically what your wrote but in a longer fashion.
2. You use filter but you want to find 1 result so the function 'find' is more suitable.

```js
const slidesArray = [["1",500],["2",750],["3",501]];

// Map an array with second entries only, then get the maximum value
let max = Math.max(...slidesArray.map(entry => entry[1]))

// Find entry with max value
let result = slidesArray.find(entry => entry[1] === max)

// Show result
console.log(result[0])
```

Comment: This is not an optimal solution. The complexity of `Math.max` is `O(n)`, Also the complexity of `Array.find` is `O(n)` (worse case). Which causes this solution's complexity `O(2n)`. You can simply do it with 1 iteration by tracking the largest one in a variable.

Comment: Same solution as https://stackoverflow.com/a/36941256

Answer (score -1):

You could introduce a helper that returns an item of a collection based on the highest value.

```js
function maxBy(iterable, fnValue) {
  var maxItem, maxValue;
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const value = fnValue(item);
    if (value <= maxValue) continue;
    maxItem = item;
    maxValue = value;
  }
  return maxItem;
}
```

The above function iterates through an iterable. For each item it executes the `fnValue` function to get a value. It then compares the value against the highest value found so far. If it's less than or equal to the max value, it will go to next item. Otherwise the max item and value will be replaced with the current item and value.

Note that comparisons with `undefined` always evaluate to `false`. So the first iteration `500 <= undefined` will produce `false`, thus setting the `maxItem` and `maxValue`.

This would allow you to do the following:

```js
const slides = [["1",500],["2",750],["3",501]];
const slide = maxBy(slides, slide => slide[1]);
console.log(slide[0]);
```

```js
const slides = [["1",500],["2",750],["3",501]];
const slide = maxBy(slides, slide => slide[1]);
console.log(slide[0]);


function maxBy(iterable, fnValue) {
  var maxItem, maxValue;
  for (const item of iterable) {
    const value = fnValue(item);
    if (value <= maxValue) continue;
    maxItem = item;
    maxValue = value;
  }
  return maxItem;
}
```